# Appending array

Tags: c, arrays

I have 2 variables:

```
int a;
char b[10];
```

I want to combine/append both data in one array:

```
temp[50];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by append both data in one array? whats the type of temp[50]? why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct stuff {
    int a;
    char b[10];
}

struct stuff temp[50]; // an array of 50 structs with 2 members each.
```

Comment: how do i access the struct member?

Comment: @kiran `temp[index].a; temp[index].b` what you have is equivalent of `temp[0].a; temp[0].b`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give us enough information about the type of temp or why you want to do that, generally it doens't make much sense to combine types. However if temp is a char array and you want to concatenate both of them for some kind of useful output, you can use sprintf:

```
int a = 10;
char b[10] = "apple";
char temp[50];

sprintf(temp, "%d %s", a, b);

/* 10 apple */
puts(temp);
```

`%d` in the sprintf is used to represent a decimal integer while `%s` is use to represent a null-terminated string.

Comment: I have data int a=10; and char[20] = "apple". I want char temp[50] to have temp = 10 apple when I call a display function. Is this helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I figured you were interested in the ASCII string representation. You might want to update your question to clarify that. I updated the code, sprintf can be used with any format you would like.

Comment: In that case this seems pretty close to what you are after.

Comment: @kiran - you should edit your question with this info, then this answers the question.  Right now the question is a little to vague.

Answer (score 0):

what is the data type of your temp[50] ?? If it is a char temp[50], then you can turn your 'int a', into a char 
using below suggestion from the very same community, stackoverflow, by JaredPar

char dig = (char)(((int)'0')+i);
[ref] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/convert-int-to-char-c

Comment: @filip-fku, if that's case, you could always break your int into 4 chars(which essentially takes up 4 char slots in your char array).  Like i stated, what is the data type for your temp[50]?  int or char or something you define(struct) that could hold an 'int' and a 'char', and then have that 'struct' array?

Comment: Exactly, but that's not exactly converting an int to a char is it? It's more like using an int to carry chars around. That might be useful, I guess it all depends on the context of this question which we don't have.

Comment: @filip-fku, i had a fast glance and got mixed up your name with the author, the you in the previous comment was supposed to be the author instead.  Yes, it would not be true 'appending' of int to char, it would be appending a list of 'ascii' characters instead.  However, i have a feeling that might be a HW question, and the teacher was supposed to ask the students to use 'struct' instead?  so that they could make an array of that 'struct'(datatype).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to mix different data types in the same array - I would advise against doing this. If you really must combine them in some way, you could use a struct.

On the other hand, technically speaking it is possible, as an int is large enough to contain a char - so you could create the array temp[] as an int type, and populate it with ints or chars from the other array..

Comment: sorry I am a beginner. Can you please tell me how I am suppose to populate the different types data in one array? Thank you

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you generally shouldn't do that. Could you tell us why you want to do that and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
char temp[50] = {a, b[0], b[1], ...};
```

If so, it's:

```
char temp[50];
temp[0] = a;
memcpy(&temp[1], b, sizeof(char) * 10);
```